# How is Filter Concatenation implemented in Tensorflow?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution, conv-neural-network

Looking at **GoogleNet** architecture you can see such blocks:
[image]

convolution operation is **tf.nn.conv2d()**

pooling is **tf.nn.max_pool()**

But I cannot find in examples and tutorials how is Filter Concatenation implemented in TF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tensorflow has [tf.concat](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#concat):

```
concatenated_tensor = tf.concat(3, [branch1, branch2, branch3, branch4])
```

where branchX are the result tensors of the different paths.